# JavaFX remove Node from ToolBar ContextMenu

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm having an issue with my usage of Toolbar. I've provided a small program that demonstrates what I'm trying to do and the issue. Basically I add a 'custom' Button to a Toolbar. The 'custom' Buttons have a X image on them and they have an action which allows them to remove themselves from the Toolbar. This works fine. The issue is when more Buttons are added to the Toolbar than there is width to show them Toolbar performs it's nice behaviour of showing the option to view a ContextMenu/popup to display the other Buttons. This also works well. The problem comes when removing the Buttons from the Toolbar. Removing Buttons that are visible on the Toolbar works well but if you try to remove Buttons from the ContextMenu, when it's made visible, it doesn't redraw itself and so the Button looks like it hasn't been removed. If the ContextMenu is hidden and then reshown the Button has been removed so it's just a redrawing issue.

Is there anyway I can force this to redraw from the Parent Node (the Toolbar) down?

```
    package ToolbarTest;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class ToolbarHolderController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    ToolBar toolBar;
    @FXML
    BorderPane borderPane;
    @FXML
    Button addButton;
    @FXML
    Button removeButton;
    @FXML
    private LinkedHashMap<String, ToggleButton> toggleButtonHash = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            ImageView closeImageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("tabclose2.png").toString()));
            String text="B:" + i.get();
            RemoveableToggleButton tButton = new RemoveableToggleButton(text, closeImageView, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (toggleButtonHash.containsKey(text)) {
                        toolBar.getItems().remove(toggleButtonHash.get(text));
                        toggleButtonHash.remove(text);
                    }
                    e.consume();
                }
            });
            toolBar.getItems().add(tButton);
            toggleButtonHash.put(text, tButton);
            i.set(i.get() + 1);
        });

        removeButton.setOnAction(e->{
                toolBar.getItems().remove(toolBar.getItems().size()-1);
            }
        );
    }

    class RemoveableToggleButton extends ToggleButton {

        private Button close = new Button();

        public RemoveableToggleButton(String text, Node graphic, EventHandler<ActionEvent> closeEvent) {
            this.close.setGraphic(graphic);
            this.close.setOnAction(closeEvent);
            this.close.setMouseTransparent(false);
            this.textProperty().set(text);
            this.setGraphic(close);
        }

    }
}
```

ToolBarHolder.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ToolbarTest.ToolbarHolderController">
   <top>
      <ToolBar fx:id="toolBar" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <HBox spacing="5.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="addButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="add" />
             <Button fx:id="removeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="remove" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have this very same problem. Through a bunch of trial and error, I was able to figure out that you not only need to remove the button from the toolbar.getItems(), but also from the Context Menu that the "overflow" button generates.

Try this:

```
// if the button is inside of a context menu, remove it from there as well
if (buttonToClose.getParent() != null &&
    buttonToClose.getParent().getParent() != null &&
    buttonToClose.getParent().getParent().getParent() != null &&
    buttonToClose.getParent().getParent().getParent() instanceof ContextMenuContent) {

    ContextMenuContent contextMenuContent = buttonToClose.getParent().getParent().getParent();
    contextMenuContent.getItemsContainer().getChildren().remove(buttonToClose.getParent());
}
```

I know it looks really hacky and has insider knowledge about the makeup of that context menu, but it works.

Comment: The only thing I needed to do was cast to ContextMenuContent, thanks very much for posting this :)